# Error <bound method Node.getCpuPowerUsage of <__main__.Node instance at 0x7f6f60c6b8c0>>

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipmi

I just want to print the PowerUsage of my system in a python script. My script is part of a monitoring script. 
and i get the error `<bound method Node.getCpuPowerUsage of <__main__.Node instance at 0x7f6f60c6b8c0>>`

```py
def getPowerUsage(self):
      self.powerUsage = os.popen("sudo ipmi-oem intelnm get-node-manager-statistics mode=globalpower | awk '$1 == \"Current\" {print $4}'").read().replace("\n", "")
      return self.powerUsage
```

```py
node1 = Node(0, 0, 0)
node1.getPowerUsage()
node1.getGpuPowerUsage()
node1.getCpuPowerUsage()
print(node1.getPowerUsage)
```

the output of the command 
`sudo ipmi-oem intelnm get-node-manager-statistics mode=globalpower | awk '$1 == \"Current\" {print $4}'").read().replace("\n", "")` looks like this

```
$sudo ipmi-oem intelnm get-node-manager-statistics mode=globalpower | awk '$1 == \"Current\" {print $4}'").read().replace("\n", "")
 185
```

Comment: You want `node1.getPowerUsage()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `print(node1.getPowerUsage)` with `print(node1.getPowerUsage())` like gmds said

Comment: there was another mistake too `$sudo ipmi-oem intelnm get-node-manager-statistics mode=globalpower | awk '$1 == \"Current\" {print $4}'.read().replace("\n", "")`